# array em um foreach php

Tags: php, array, foreach

Vou tentar ser objetivo na dúvida:

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php

foreach ($modelo as $k => $v) {
    $sql_ = "SELECT * FROM pedido WHERE modelo LIKE '%".$v."%' ORDER BY id ASC";
    $disp_sql_ = $mysqli->query($sql_);

    while ($data_ = $disp_sql_->fetch_array()) { 
        $quantidade_    += ($data_['total'] * $data_['kit']);
    }
}
```

O total da variável `$quantidade`, tem o output com soma, de todos os modelos.

No banco de dados está assim:

```
valor 1 = 20 ($modelo 1)
valor 2 = 30 ($modelo 1)
valor 3 = 50 ($modelo 1)
valor 4 = 50 ($modelo 2)
valor 5 = 50 ($modelo 2)
```

A variável `$quantidade` me trás isso:

```
$quantidade = 200;
```

O que eu gostaria é que me trouxesse o resultado da seguinte forma:

```
$quantidade = array([0] => 100, [2] => 100)
```

uma somatória a cada alteração de modelo (cada alteração de foreach), resultados em um array.

Comment: inicia a $quantidade antes do while `$quantidade_ = array(); while (){ $quantidade_ = array( //seucaldulo ) }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente separar os valores no array dentro do seu `for` da seguinte maneira:

```
<?php

$quantidade = [];

foreach ($modelo as $k => $v) {
    $sql_ = "SELECT * FROM pedido WHERE modelo LIKE '%".$v."%' ORDER BY id ASC";
    $disp_sql_ = $mysqli->query($sql_);

    while ($data_ = $disp_sql_->fetch_array()) { 
        // Se a chave não existir cria uma nova com o valor 0
        $quantidade[$data_['id_modelo']] = $quantidade[$data_['id_modelo']] ?? 0;

        // Soma normalmente
        $quantidade[$data_['id_modelo']] += $data_['total'] * $data_['kit'];
    }
}
```

Porém, uma maneira melhor seria fazer estes cálculos no banco de dados, utilizando a função [`SUM()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) juntamente com [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html). Exemplo:

```
<?php

$quantidade = [];

foreach ($modelo as $k => $v) {
    $sql_ = <<<SQL
        SELECT 
            id_modelo,
            SUM(total * kit) as soma
        FROM pedido 
        WHERE modelo LIKE '%$v%'
        GROUP BY id_modelo,
        ORDER BY id ASC;
SQL;
    $disp_sql_ = $mysqli->query($sql_);

    while ($data_ = $disp_sql_->fetch_array()) { 
        // Já retorna o somatório do banco de dados
        $quantidade[$data_['id_modelo']] = $data_['soma']];
    }
}
```

Comment: obrigado Fernando, consegui fazendo a conta já na consulta do banco, valeu mesmo!

Comment: Que bom que deu certo!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode inicializar a quantidade fora do loop

```
<?php
$quantidade_ = array();
foreach ($modelo as $k => $v) {
    $sql_ = "SELECT * FROM pedido WHERE modelo LIKE '%".$v."%' GROUP BY id ASC";
    $disp_sql_ = $mysqli->query($sql_);

    while ($data_ = $disp_sql_->fetch_array()) { 
        $quantidade_[] =  array(
               ($data_['total'] * $data_['kit']);
           )
    }
}
```

Ou inicializar assim:

```
 $quantidade_ = []
```

e alimentar assim:

```
 $quantidade[] =  ($data_['total'] * $data_['kit']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira simples de resolver isso:

```
<?php

foreach ( $modelo as $k => $v ) {
    $sql_      = "SELECT * FROM pedido WHERE modelo LIKE '%".$v."%' ORDER BY id ASC";
    $disp_sql_ = $mysqli->query( $sql_ );

    $ultimo_valor = 0;
    while ( $data_ = $disp_sql_->fetch_array() ) { 
        $quantidade_[$k] = $ultimo_valor + ( $data_['total'] * $data_['kit'] );
        $ultimo_valor   += ( $data_['total'] * $data_['kit'] );
    }
}
```

Print de como vai ficar:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 20
    [1] => 50
    [2] => 100
    [3] => 150
    [4] => 200
)
```

Comment: Kayo o AP precisa somar agrupado por modelo, sua solução faz um somatório acumulado. Não acho que seja isso que ele quer.

Comment: Pois é amigo, coloquei a resposta mas com algumas dúvidas se era isso mesmo que ele precisava.

Comment: Então ficamos no aguardo que ele comente aqui. :D  Na pior da hipóteses não é, mas pode ser de ajuda.

Comment: Kayo e fernando, sim, já havia tentado dessa maneira e ele trás a soma acumulado, não me resolveu, pensei em mil formas mas sem sucesso, resolvi postar aqui pra ver se alguém consegue me salvar, obrigado pela ajuda